# Proving that $\boldsymbol \nabla \times (U(r) \hat{r}) = 0 $

Tags: multivariable-calculus, spherical-coordinates

I was just checking to see if I wsa doing this right, as it isn't a formal proof. Just showing the identity.

Let $U(r) \hat{r}$ b a vector in spherical coordinates. Given that the vector is only dependent on r, and there's no $\hat{\phi}$ or $\hat{\theta}$ component, that means that in the usual formula for the curl in spherical coordinates: $$\nabla \times U(r)\hat{r} = \hat{r} \frac{1}{\sin \theta}\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}(u_{\phi}\sin\theta) - \frac{\partial u_{\theta}}{\partial\theta} \right]+ \hat{\theta} \frac{1}{r}\left[\frac{1}{\sin \theta}\frac{\partial u_r}{\partial\phi}- \frac{\partial}{\partial r}(ru_{\phi}) \right]+\hat{\phi} \frac{1}{r}\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial\phi}(ru_{\theta})- \frac{\partial u_r}{\partial r}\right]$$

the $u_{\theta}$ and $u_{\phi}$ are just zero, since the original function has only a radial component. Since they go to zero all those partial derivatives go to zero, correct?

Comment: Correct, but the last term in brackets should have a $\frac{\partial u_r}{\partial \theta}$ instead of $\frac{\partial u_r}{\partial r}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $U(r)$ is scalar function and you want to show that $\vec F(r) = U(r)\hat r$ has zero curl. Than easiest way to do this is:
$$
\int_0^r U(s) ds = V(r)
$$
$$
U(r) \hat r = V'(r)\hat r  = \nabla V(r)
$$
but
$$
\text{curl } \text{grad } V(r) = 0
$$

Comment: and thanks to you as well. I was thinking there had to be an easier way (or more elegant).

Comment: Always try to stay out of the coordinates. They makes things complicated.

Comment: Plus if you picture vector field in form $U(r) \hat r$ than from picture it can be easily seen that it can be written as gradient of some scalar function. And fact that curl of gradient is zero is well known fact.

Answer (score 0):

**Fell asleep last night after hitting the "Post" button by accident!  Fixed 'er up first thing this AM, after reading Jesse's corrections.  So here goes the (hopefully) final version:**

I'm having a little trouble with your notation since in both the title and at the start of the second paragraph you seem to be referring to a vector field of the form $U(r) \hat r$ (though a parenthesis appears to be missing in the title), where $\hat r = (x, y, z)^T$ is the usual radial vector and $U(r)$ is a spherically symmetric function, i.e., one that only depends on the radius $r = \Vert \hat r \Vert$.  But then when you write out the component formula it's not very clear to me what the $u_r, u_\theta, u_\phi$ refer to, unless perchance it is to the components of $U(r) \hat {\mathbf r}$ in spherical coordinates.

NEVERTHELESS, if what you really want to do is show that $\nabla \times U(r) \hat r = 0$ for spherically stmmetric functions $U(r)$, then perhaps the easiest thing to do is use the identity

$\nabla \times (f \hat V) = \nabla f \times \hat V + f \nabla \times \hat V, \tag{1}$

a standard result from vector calculus, which can easily be derived from the well-known "determinant formula" for $\nabla \times$:

$\nabla \times \hat Y = \begin{bmatrix} \hat {\mathbf i} & \hat {\mathbf j} & \hat {\mathbf k} \\ \frac{\partial}{\partial x} &  \frac{\partial}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial}{\partial z} \\ \hat Y_x & \hat Y_y & \hat Y_z \end{bmatrix}. \tag{2}$

If we set $\hat Y = f \hat V$ in (2) and grind, we get

$\nabla \times f \hat V = (\frac{\partial}{\partial y} (f \hat V_z) - (\frac{\partial}{\partial z} (f \hat V_y))\hat {\mathbf i} + (\frac{\partial}{\partial z} (f \hat V_x) - (\frac{\partial}{\partial x} (f \hat V_z))\hat {\mathbf j}$
$+ (\frac{\partial}{\partial x} (f \hat V_y) - (\frac{\partial}{\partial y} (f \hat V_x))\hat {\mathbf k}, \tag{3}$

or

$\nabla \times f \hat V = ((f_y \hat V_z + f \hat V_{z, y}) -  (f_z \hat V_y + f \hat V_{y, z}))\hat {\mathbf i} + ((f_z \hat V_x + f \hat V_{x, z}) - (f_x \hat V_z + f \hat V_{z, x}))\hat {\mathbf j}$
$+ ((f_x \hat V_y + f \hat V_{y, x}) - (f_y \hat V_x + f \hat V_{x, y}))\hat {\mathbf k}, \tag{4}$

after which some simple algebraic re-arrangement yields (1).  For example, the coefficient of $\hat{\mathbf i}$ is

$(f_y \hat V_z - f_z \hat V_y) + f(\hat V_{z, y} - \hat V_{y, z}). \tag{5}$

In (3), (4), and (5), I have used subscript notation for partials, e.g. $f_x = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ and $\hat V_{x,y} = \frac{\partial V_x}{\partial y}$ etc.  This formula may also be found in [this wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_calculus_identities).

Applying (1) to $U(r) \hat r$, we have

$\nabla \times U(r) \hat r = \nabla U(r) \times \hat r + U(r) \nabla \times \hat r. \tag{6}$

Now

$\nabla \times \hat r = 0, \tag{7}$

which is easy to see by direct calculation, using (2) if you like, so we are left with

$\nabla \times U(r) \hat r = \nabla U(r) \times \hat r; \tag{8}$

but I claim that for any function $U(r)$ which only depends on $r$, $\nabla U(r)$ is in fact collinear with $\hat r$; to see this, write

$U(r) = U((x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}), \tag{9}$

so that for example

$\frac{\partial U}{\partial x}(r) = \frac{dU}{dr}(r) \frac{x}{r}, \tag{10}$

by the chain rule, since $\frac{\partial r}{\partial x} = \frac{x}{r}$.  Similar expressions hold for the $y$ and $z$ derivatives as well.  Now (10), when combined with its $y$ and $z$ counterparts, gives

$\nabla U(r) = r^{-1}\frac{dU}{dr}(r) \hat r, \tag{11}$,

and substituting this in (8) yields

$\nabla \times U(r) \hat r = r^{-1}\frac{dU}{dr}(r) \hat r \times \hat r = 0, \tag{12}$

since $\hat r \times \hat r$ vanishes identically.  Thus we see that

$\nabla \times U(r) \hat r = 0, \tag{13}$

as was required.  QED.

**CAVEAT:**  One should of course take care applying these or any derivative formula to a function or vector field at the origin $(0, 0, 0)$ where $r = 0$, since $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}$ is continuous but not differentiable there.  I believe similar remarks apply to the answer given by tom.  But if $U(r)$ is sufficiently smooth everywhere, then I do b'lieve she'll fly, Wilbur!

Hope this helps.  Cheers!

and as always

***Fiat Lux!***

[Proving that $\nabla \times (U(r) \hat{r} = 0 $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/497293/proving-that-nabla-times-ur-hatr-0/497400#497400)

Comment: i edited it a bit to make it clearer...