# Question on Curl F

Tags: multivariable-calculus

The problem in the book asks what the curl of $\operatorname{curl}\vec F(\vec r)= \frac {\vec r}{\|\vec r\|}$. Can someone give me a good explanation on why the curl will be zero? I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Did you try plotting the vector field?

Comment: I wasn't given a vector field, the problem is copied directly from the book.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function $\frac{\vec{r}}{\| \vec{r}\|}$ is the gradient of the scalar field $f(\vec{r})=\|\vec{r}\|$. Proceed using the identity $$\text{curl grad } f=0. $$

Comment: Thanks! I really appreciate your help!

Comment: @ user1337:  simpler though less general than my approach; in my penchant for abstraction, I lost sight of the fact that $(\vec r / \Vert \vec r \Vert)$ is a gradient! +1!

Answer (score 1):

Basically, for any function $f(x, y, z)$ and vector field $\mathbf V(x, y, z)$, we have

$\nabla \times (f \mathbf V) = \nabla f \times \mathbf V + f \nabla \times \mathbf V; \tag{1}$

in the present case, taking $\mathbf V = \vec r$, it is easy to see by direct calculation that

$\nabla \times \mathbf V = \nabla \times \vec r = 0, \tag{2}$

and since

$\nabla (1 / \Vert \vec r \Vert)$ is collinear with $\vec r$, we also have

$\nabla (1 / \Vert \vec r \Vert) \times \vec r = 0; \tag{3}$

plugging everything into (1) gives the desired result.

Though user1337's answer is of course correct, the above shows how this problem fits into a somewhat more general pattern; see my answers to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/493022/showing-proving-curl-identity-nabla-times-left-frac1r2-hat-r-righ).

Hope this helps.  Cheerio,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***